# Правомерность использования API cian.ru

Tags: лицензирование

Хотел бы выяснить, могу ли я использовать API сайта cian.ru
Публично об API нигде не написано, но я смог найти пример использования на одном из сервисов Циана. [Вот пример ссылки](http://map.cian.ru/ajax/map/roundabout/?deal_type=1&flats=yes&currency=2&type=4&room0=1&room1=1&room2=1&room3=1&engine_version=2&in_polygon[0]=55.692383_37.321835,55.692383_37.675457,55.759616_37.675457,55.759616_37.321835&_=1466708040958)

Нужно это для автоматического добавления квартир в базу данных моего сайта загружая списки с этого самого API

Не противоречит ли это каким-либо лицензиям?

Comment: А почему бы вам не спросить у разработчиков сайта? Если они разрешают, всё хорошо. Если нет — не делайте так.

Answer (score 6):

Если нет никаких публичных документов по API, то Вы, конечно, можете им воспользоваться, только вот проблема - разработчики могут его поменять в любой момент времени и Ваш проект сломается.

Более того - лицензионное соглашение CIAN.RU лежит [здесь](http://cian.ru/help/about/rules-legal/). Как я понимаю, использование их API подпадает под пункт:

> 7.2.3. использовать без специального на то разрешения Администрации Сайтов автоматизированные скрипты (программы) для сбора информации на
>   Сайтах и/или взаимодействия с Сайтами и их функционалом;

Поэтому если данные оттуда действительно нужны для серьезного проекта на систематической основе - рекомендую связаться с разработчиками.